# js-interop: How to access the input data in the callback function?

Tags: dart

I've written a wrapper class to access Google Sheet using the javascripts API (as Dart version of Google API is not working). In the callback function, I can see the data are stored in the `body` and `results` field in the debugger on Dartium but could not access them from Dart. Any suggestion would be much appreciated. The program is using Dart 1.18.

[image]
[image]

Javascript Code

```
var googleStorage = new GoogleStorage();
function GoogleStorage() {

    this.CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXX';
    this.SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"];
}

GoogleStorage.prototype.authorize = function(handleAuthResult) {
    gapi.auth.authorize( {
        client_id: this.CLIENT_ID, scope: this.SCOPES, immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);

    return false;
}

GoogleStorage.prototype.loadTraitUrl = function(handleLoadUrlResult) {
    console.log("loadConnectionUrl");
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
    gapi.client.load(discoveryUrl).then(handleLoadUrlResult);
}

GoogleStorage.prototype.listTraits = function(successFunc, errorFunc) {

   console.log("listData");

   gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: 'YYYYY',
        range: 'Taits!B8:AQ',
   }).then(successFunc, errorFunc);

}
```

Dart Wrapper Class

```
@JS()
library my_workbench.lib.common.google_storage;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('googleStorage')
class GoogleStorage {
    external static authorize(Function handler);
    external static traitLoadUrl(Function handler);
    external static listTraits(Function success, Function error);
}
```

Dart Program

```
main() async {
  querySelector("#my_button").onClick.listen(handleEvent);
}

void handleEvent(MouseEvent event) {
  print("Button Clicked");

  GoogleStorage.authorize(
      allowInterop((var authResult) {
          handleAuthResult(authResult);
      })
  );
}

void handleAuthResult(var authResult) {
    print("Successful Authenticated: ${authResult}");

   GoogleStorage.traitLoadUrl(
      allowInterop((_) {
          handleLoadUrlResult();
      })
   );
}

void handleLoadUrlResult() {
    print("Successful loaded URL");
    GoogleStorage.listTraits(
        allowInterop((var response) {
            // var range = response.body;
            print("Success: ${response.body}");
        }), allowInterop((var response) {
            print("Success: ${response}");
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution. The problem is apparently caused by `allowInterop()` not working with js `response` that contains non supported data type. By returning just the array list of data, it works perfectly. The js list is correctly mapped over to Dart's list by `allowInterop()`.

Javascript Code

```
GoogleStorage.prototype.listTraits = function(successFunc, errorFunc) {

   console.log("listData");

   gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
       spreadsheetId: 'YYYYY',
       range: 'Taits!B8:AQ',
   }).then(function(response) {
       successFunc(response.result.values);
   }, function(response) {
       errorFunc(response.result.error.message);
   });

}
```

Dart Program

```
void handleLoadUrlResult() {

    print("Successful loaded URL");
    GoogleStorage.listTraits(
        allowInterop((var response) {
            print("Success: ${response.length}");
        }), allowInterop((var response) {
            print("Failed: ${response}");
    }));
}
```